# How do I get a timestamp on other machines in the LAN?

Tags: php, timestamp

cmd by net time 192.168.0.2 / set / y. By synchronizing time.
How can that php get 192.268.0.2 timestamp on this machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this perhaps

```
<?php

    $output=array();
    $host='192.168.0.2';
    $cmd=sprintf( 'net time \\\\%s', $host );

    $output=shell_exec( $cmd );
    echo $output;

?>
```